# Excel table reference difference between [@column] and [column]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel and some equations in columns for all rows.

I have equation like this: `=IF([@C1]=0,[@C2],MIN([@C1], [@C2]))`

and then like this: `=IF([C1]=0,[C2],MIN([C1], [C2]))`

Goal is to check column `C1` and if it is not `0`, use minimum between `C1` and `C2`.

If I use first option with `@`, it works ok, while second always returns `0`, no matter what is in `C1` or `C2`.

What is the difference between equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With @ you refer to the same row as where your formula is. Without the @, you make reference to the entire column.

But your formula is confusing as C1 is usually not a column but a cell in Excel. Typical syntax for using structured references with Excel tables is `TableName[ColumnName]` to refer to a column of a table.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. I use `TableName[ColumnName]` if I need reference outside table. Inside the table, you can use only `[ColumnName]`.

Comment: Indeed, you can even use only the column name if the formula is next to the table (without any empty columns in between), as Excel will automatically expand the table (so as you rightly said, the formula will then be inside the table). But the `C1` name itself was a bit confusing, but probably it makes sense for your table.